# Not able to edit Lookup Filter for custom field

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, lookup-filter

I need to change the Filter Criteria of the lookup filter for a custom field. But then i edit the custom field I am not able to edit the lookup filter option.

[image]

Comment: Is this a field from an installed package?

Comment: Yes. From package only